# relative path for importing python files

Tags: python, import, include-path

Is there any equivalent relative path for python imports?

```
$ cat main.py
from some_dir.utils import do_something
print(do_something(19))

$ python3.8 main.py
939 <----- good
```

I copied my `main.py` to another directory, and tried to adjust the relative path:

```
$ cat another_dir/main.py 
from ..some_dir.utils import do_something
print(do_something(19))

$ python3.8 another_dir/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "another_dir/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..some_dir.utils import do_something
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Here is my directory layout:

```
$ tree
.
├── another_dir
│   └── main.py
├── main.py
└── some_dir
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   └── utils.cpython-38.pyc
    └── utils.py

3 directories, 6 files
```